# Comparing two dataframes without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two similar structured dataframes that represent two periods in time, say Jul 2020 and Aug 2020. The data in it is forecasted and/or realised revenue data from several company sources like CRM and accouting application. The columns contain data on clients, product, quantity, price, revenue, period, etc. Now I want to see what happened between these to months by comparing the two dataframes.

I tried to do this by renaming some of the columns like quantity, price and revenue and then merge the two dataframes on client, product and period. After that I calculate the difference on the quanity, price and revenue.

However I run into a problem... Suppose one specific customer has closed a contract with us to purchase two specific products (abc & xyz) every month for the next two years. That means that in our July forecast we can include these two items as revenue. In reality this list is much longer with other contracts and also expected revenue that is in the weighted pipeline.

This is a small extract from the total forecast for our specific client.

```
    Client  Product Period  Stage       Qty Price   Rev
0   A       abc     2020-07 contracted  1   100     100
1   A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1   50      50
```

Now suppose this client descides to purchase a second product xyz and we get another contract for this. Than it looks like this for July:

```
    Client  Product Period  Stage       Qty Price   Rev
0   A       abc     2020-07 contracted  1   100     100
1   A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1   50      50
2   A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1   50      50
```

Now suppose we are a month later and from our accounting sytem we drew the realised revenue that looks like this (so what we forecasted became reality):

```
    Client  Product Period  Stage       Qty Price   Rev
0   A       abc     2020-07 realised    1   100     100
1   A       xyz     2020-07 realised    2   50      100
```

And now I want to compare them by merging the two df's after renaming some of the columns.

```
def rename_column(df_name, col_name, first_forecast_period):
    col_name = df_name.rename(columns={col_name: col_name + '_' + first_forecast_period}, inplace=True)
    return df_name

rename_column(df_1, 'Stage', '1') 
rename_column(df_1, 'Price', '1')
rename_column(df_1, 'Qty', '1')
rename_column(df_1, 'Rev', '1')
rename_column(df_2, 'Stage', '2') 
rename_column(df_2, 'Price', '2')
rename_column(df_2, 'Qty', '2')
rename_column(df_2, 'Rev', '2')

result_1 = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how ='outer')
```

And then some math to get the differences:

```
result_1['Qty_diff'] = result1['Quantity_2'] - result1['Quantity_1']
result_1['Price_diff'] = result1['Price_2'] - result1['Price_1']
result_1['Rev_diff'] = result1['Rev_2'] - result1['Rev_1']
```

This results in:

```
    Client  Product Period  Stage_1     Qty_1   Price_1 Rev_1   Stage_2  Qty_2  Price_2 Rev_2   Qty_diff    Price_diff  Rev_diff
 0  A       abc     2020-07 contracted  1       100     100     realised 1      100     100     0           0           0
 1  A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1       50      50      realised 2      50      100     1           0           50
 2  A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1       50      50      realised 2      50      100     1           0           50
```

So, the problem is that in the third line the realised part is included a second time. Since the forecast and the reality are the same, the outcome should have been:

```
    Client  Product Period  Stage_1     Qty_1   Price_1 Rev_1   Stage_2  Qty_2  Price_2 Rev_2   Qty_diff    Price_diff  Rev_diff
 0  A       abc     2020-07 contracted  1       100     100     realised 1      100     100     0           0           0
 1  A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1       50      50      realised 2      50      100     1           0           50
 2  A       xyz     2020-07 contracted  1       50      50      realised 0      0       0       -1          0           -50
```

And therefor I get a total revenue difference of 100 (+50 and +50), instead of 0 (+50 and -50). Is there any way this can be solved with merging the two DF's or do I need to start thinking in another direction. If so, then any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Consider grouping `df_1` before merging the two, that way when you merge you will have unique rows :)

Comment: Will the price always be the same for two different rows of the same product?

Comment: @Roelant: Grouping might be a solution, but also eliminates information. In the actual dataframe the second line has 'new sales' and the third 'upsell' as contract_sort.

Comment: @RichieV: In this case yes, because there is a signed contract with a fixed price. But in other cases prices can also differ. For example, a new prospect will be included in the sales pipeline with the standard price, but might end up a higher or lower price in the contract.

Comment: Notice if you add a groupby at the end of your code you can sum the diff columns and get net difference by cliente-product, which will be zero in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably get the totals for client-product-period on both dfs to be safe. Assuming all rows in df_1 are 'contracted', you can do:

```
df_1 = (df_1.groupby(['Client', 'Prooduct', 'Period'])
    .agg({'Stage': 'first', 'Qty': sum, 'Price': 'first', 'Rev': sum})
    # if price can vary between rows of the same product-client
    # .agg({'Stage': 'first', 'Qty': sum, 'Price': 'mean', 'Rev': sum})

# same for df_2
```

Now you can `merge` both dfs with:

```
df_merged = df_1.merge(df_2)
```

The result will add suffixes to duplicate columns, `_x` and `_y` for df_1 and df_2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for this. Like I said above, it eliminates some info, but I guess an solution that completely solves this involves probably a lot of coding...

Comment: I understand. That's why it is important to include sample data as small as possible but that still represents the full complexity of the problem.

Comment: You need to include .reset_index() after groupby to prevent getting a dataframe with a  hierarchical index. Then the merging will crash.